# Remove linespacing between tags in css

Tags: css, markdown, pandoc

I am struggling with targeting the current hierachy of tags (CSS newbie). What I am trying to achieve is removal of the linespace/linebreak/whitepace between the references in the following example:

References

1. Wille, N., Badia, X., Bonsel, G., Burström, K., Cavrini, G., Devlin, N., … Ravens-Sieberer, U. (2010). Development of the EQ-5D-Y: A child-friendly version of the EQ-5D. Quality of Life Research, 19(6), 875–886. doi:10.1007/s11136-010-9648-y
2. Ravens-Sieberer, U., Wille, N., Badia, X., Bonsel, G., Burström, K., Cavrini, G., … Greiner, W. (2010). Feasibility, reliability, and validity of the EQ-5D-Y: Results from a multinational study. Quality of Life Research, 19(6), 887–897. doi:10.1007/s11136-010-9649-x

I am using markdown with pandoc build this reference list, and this output is what I have to work with:

```
<h3 id="references" class="unnumbered">
References
</h3>
<div id="refs" class="references">
<div id="ref-WilleDevelopmentEQ5DYchildfriendly2010">
<p>
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>Wille, N., Badia, X., Bonsel, G., Burström, K., Cavrini, G., Devlin, N., … Ravens-Sieberer, U. (2010). Development of the EQ-5D-Y: A child-friendly version of the EQ-5D. <em>Quality of Life Research</em>, <em>19</em>(6), 875–886. doi:<a href="https://doi.org/10.1007/s11136-010-9648-y">10.1007/s11136-010-9648-y</a>
</p>
</div>
<div id="ref-Ravens-SiebererFeasibilityreliabilityvalidity2010">
<p>
<ol start="2" style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>Ravens-Sieberer, U., Wille, N., Badia, X., Bonsel, G., Burström, K., Cavrini, G., … Greiner, W. (2010). Feasibility, reliability, and validity of the EQ-5D-Y: Results from a multinational study. <em>Quality of Life Research</em>, <em>19</em>(6), 887–897. doi:<a href="https://doi.org/10.1007/s11136-010-9649-x">10.1007/s11136-010-9649-x</a>
</p>
</div>
```

I have tried to give `font-size: 0` for the parent `div id refs` and for the `class references` and separate font-size for the specific-ids `<div id="ref-...">` using wildcard `div[id^="ref-"]`. I have read a lot of the similar questions, but not been able to solve this. I suspect that I must target the `<p>`, `<ol>` or `<li>` tags within the specific `div`, but haven' been able to get this to work.

Update:
Thanks for repllies, I see that some clarification is necessary;
1. The structure above is generated automatically, and I would prefer to not edit the HTML manually,
2. The references is the end of a long document where I probably need p tags to be as they are in order for the main text to have certain properties such as font, font size and linespacing.

Comment: A list shouldn't be inside a paragraph. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

Answer (score 2):

By default most browsers define a top and bottom margin on `<p>` tags of `1em` (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp)). So try to remove that with:

```
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```